# Young's Double Slit, phase difference and path difference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, waves, interference

To produce an interference pattern, the light sources must be coherent right? Coherent by definition means constant phase difference between waves of the *same frequency* so that means waves can be coherent if they have different wavelengths but the same frequency. My question is, can an interference pattern be produced if they have constant phase difference (coherent, determined by their frequencies) but different path difference, as they have different wavelengths(determined by their wavelengths)? I'm an a level student trying to clear my doubts, thank you in advance!

Comment: If light waves have the same wavelength, they also have the same frequency.  Based on that fact, can you re-phrase your question?

Comment: let's say they have the same frequency but different speeds, so resulting in different wavelengths, is it possible for them to produce an interference pattern?

Comment: Yes phase difference is a shift in one wave relative to the other, phase difference is not related to frequency and wavelength. The patten is best produced with monochromatic light .... and probably gets even sharper as the phase difference is reduced.  It's a complicated subject.

Comment: Light all moves at the same speed.  Wavelength times frequency equals speed.

Comment: That is not strictly true, unless the light paths are all traveling through the same medium and the light is monochromatic.  But in a vacuum, all light, x-rays, radio waves, and other electromagnetic radiation moves at the same speed.

Comment: Oh yea, the waves will always travel at the same speed if the medium is the same. Thank you, I think I’ve cleared my doubt. @S.McGrew